# Knockout Filter observableArray against another observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

Let's say I have an observableArray named completeArray and another observableArray named pickedArray, this second array(pickedArray) contains some of the objects of the completeArray. From these 2 arrays, I need to make another observableArray which will contain all the objects in my completeArray which are NOT IN the pickedArray. If anyone can help me how it is done please comment if you need to clarify something. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) array of the difference between `completeArray` and `pickedArray`.

## Javascript

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.completeArray = ko.observableArray([{id: 1, name: "john"}, {id: 2, name: "bill"}, {id: 3, name: "tom"}]);
    self.pickedArray = ko.observableArray([{id: 1, name: "john"}, {id: 3, name: "tom"}]);

    self.diffArray = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.completeArray(), function(completeItem) {
            var sameItem = false;

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.pickedArray(), function(pickedItem) {
                if(pickedItem.id == completeItem.id && pickedItem.name == completeItem.name) {
                    sameItem = true;
                    return; // break out of this loop
                }
            });

            return !sameItem;
        });
    }, self);
};

$(function () {
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

## HTML

```
<h1>Complete Array</h1>
<div data-bind="foreach: completeArray()">
    <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
</div>

<h1>Picked Array</h1>
<div data-bind="foreach: pickedArray()">
    <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
</div>

<h1>Diff Array</h1>
<div data-bind="foreach: diffArray()">
    <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
</div>
```

## Output

Complete Array
john bill tom

Picked Array
john tom

Diff Array
bill

## Example

http://jsfiddle.net/jdtjmy6u/3/

Comment: Sweet! this is near perfect but not compatible to my array as my observableArray has 2 values on each object, {id,name},{id,name} what do I need to modify to make it compare the ID value of my observableArray objects?

Comment: Do you think there's a way to make this work with observableArray of objects?